# Execute js script into Windows 10 webView

Tags: javascript, c#, win-universal-app

I'd like to run a js function that is not written into loaded html page, for example we have a simple html page with button, and I'd like to disable the button using an external js script:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <button id="my_button" type="button" onclick="">Click Me!</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and I have my script form a file:

```
 function disableFun() {
 document.getElementById("my_button").disabled = true;
 }
```

as is mentioned in [official doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) there is a API method `InvokeScriptAsync(string scriptName, string[] arguments)` but is mentioned that we must already have the script into html loaded page.

Any advices are apreciated!

P.S. in android we do it very simple `webView.loadUrl('my script code')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use InvokeScriptAsync with the JavaScript eval function to inject content into the web page.

see `Interacting with WebView content` section of [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br227702(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)%3bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true).

So to disable the button, you can use the following codes in your cs file:

```
String scriptStr = @"document.getElementById('your_buttonId').disabled=true";
await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new String[] {scriptStr});
```